# FTDI only shows up in lsusb, not under /dev/ttyUSBx

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, usb, ftdi

I have an FTDI adapter which used to work just fine under pretty much any version of Ubuntu. Now, I reflashed my board and I am having trouble accessing the serial port. The adapter shows up with lsusb, but it doesn't show up under the serial ports with ls /dev/tty*

Does anyone know if there's an easy fix for that?

Thanks,

-Marc

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you need to compile the ftdi_sio.ko file against your kernel (important to also update the local version in menuconfig) by hand and then import that. Afterwards everything works again...